# swift - detecting touch in a path

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cgpath

I have some isometric tiles in my scene. There frames overlap, so I'm using a path with the shape of an isometric Tile and check if the touch land inside.

My problem is i detect the touch, but only along the path, not inside the path. Something must be wrong with my path or the way i use it.

This is the code in "touchesEnded" method:

```
for actualTouch in touches
        {
            let SKnode = self.nodeAtPoint(actualTouch.locationInNode(self))
            let spriteNode = SKnode as! SKSpriteNode
            if spriteNode.name != nil{
                let tileSize = CGSizeMake(75, 38)
                let locationInNode = actualTouch.locationInNode(SKnode)

                let isometricPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
                CGPathMoveToPoint(isometricPath, nil, 0, -(tileSize.height / 2))
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(isometricPath, nil, (tileSize.width / 2), 0)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(isometricPath, nil, 0, (tileSize.height / 2))
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(isometricPath, nil, -(tileSize.width / 2), 0)
                CGPathCloseSubpath(isometricPath)
                CGPathMoveToPoint(isometricPath, nil, 0, 0)
                let isometricPathRef = isometricPath as CGPathRef

                if CGPathContainsPoint(isometricPathRef, nil, locationInNode, true) == true
                {
                    print("touchedTile:\(spriteNode.name!)")
                    spriteNode.alpha = 1
                }

            }
        }
```

Can u please help me to see my mistake? 
Thank you.

Comment: "let isometricPathRef = isometricPath as CGPathRef" maybe i cannot convert it into an opaque path. Or: "CGPathContainsPoint(isometricPathRef, nil, locationInNode, true) == true" this function not give me the point inside the path.. these 2 things. The error must be there because the rest is working

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to iterate over all the touched nodes and not over "touches"

```
let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))
        for node in nodes
        {

            let spriteNode = node as! SKSpriteNode
            if spriteNode.name != nil{
                let tileSize = CGSizeMake(75, 38)
                let locationInNode = touch.locationInNode(node)

                let isometricPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
                CGPathMoveToPoint(isometricPath, nil, 0, -(tileSize.height / 2))
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(isometricPath, nil, (tileSize.width / 2), 0)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(isometricPath, nil, 0, (tileSize.height / 2))
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(isometricPath, nil, -(tileSize.width / 2), 0)
                CGPathCloseSubpath(isometricPath)
                let isometricPathRef = isometricPath as CGPathRef

                print("element")
                if CGPathContainsPoint(isometricPathRef, nil, locationInNode, true) == true
                {
                    print("touchedTile:\(spriteNode.name!)")
                    spriteNode.alpha = 1
                }

            }
        }
```